# Unable to connect to smtp server when running from intellij

Tags: spring, grails, intellij-idea

I have a block of code, that sends email by connecting to SMTP server. (Grails 2.4.4 project)

1. When i run it in eclipse, everything works fine,
2. When i run in intellij idea (2016.1.2), I get MailSendException

   org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
     nested exception is:
       java.net.SocketException: Connection reset. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
     nested exception is:
       java.net.SocketException: Connection reset; message exception details (1) are:
   Failed message 1:
   javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;

Does any one have any idea of what is going on?

Comment: check your firewall. it might be blocking ports for intellij process